# How can I programmatically determine the default value of a function parameter?

Tags: function, powershell, parameters, default-value

Consider the following function:

```
function f {param($x = 42)}
```

`$x` has a default value of 42.  Suppose I have a bunch of functions whose parameters I want to test programmatically for, among other things, their default values.  Those other things I am able to discover using the objects returned using one of the following commands:

```
Get-Item function:/f | % Parameters | % x | % Attributes
Get-Help f | % Parameters | % parameter
```

Those commands output the following:

```
Position                        : 0
ParameterSetName                : __AllParameterSets
Mandatory                       : False
ValueFromPipeline               : False
ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName : False
ValueFromRemainingArguments     : False
HelpMessage                     : 
HelpMessageBaseName             : 
HelpMessageResourceId           : 
DontShow                        : False
TypeId                          : System.Management.Automation.ParameterAttribute

name             : x
required         : false
pipelineInput    : false
isDynamic        : false
parameterSetName : (All)
parameterValue   : Object
type             : @{name=Object}
position         : 0
aliases          : None
```

There doesn't seem to be any clue as to the default value.

How can I programmatically determine the default value of a function parameter?

Comment: `$((Get-Item function:/f).ScriptBlock.Ast.Body.ParamBlock.Parameters.Where{ $_.Name.VariablePath.UserPath -eq 'x' }).DefaultValue.SafeGetValue()`

Comment: @PetSerAl That's worth an anwer to vote up.

Comment: Thanks @PetSerAl.  That works.  Can you make it an answer so that I can correct the typos?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use syntax tree to find default value expression for parameter.

```
function f {
    param(
        $x = 42,
        $y = 6*7,
        $z = (Get-Random)
    )
}

$Parameters = (Get-Item function:\f).ScriptBlock.Ast.Body.ParamBlock.Parameters
$xDefaultValue = $($Parameters.Where{$_.Name.VariablePath.UserPath -eq 'x'}).DefaultValue
$yDefaultValue = $($Parameters.Where{$_.Name.VariablePath.UserPath -eq 'y'}).DefaultValue
$zDefaultValue = $($Parameters.Where{$_.Name.VariablePath.UserPath -eq 'z'}).DefaultValue
```

You can than use `SafeGetValue()` method of syntax tree node to retrieve constant value, but it does not work with expressions.

```
$xDefaultValue.SafeGetValue()
$yDefaultValue.SafeGetValue()
$zDefaultValue.SafeGetValue()
```