# How to return the default value of a parameter in the correct parameter type?

Tags: powershell

The code below will retrieve the default values of the parameters used in a function or scriptfile:

```
Function Get-DefaultParameterValuesHC {
    [OutputType([hashtable])]
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [String]$Path
    )
    $ast = (Get-Command $Path).ScriptBlock.Ast

    $selectParams = @{
        Property = @{ 
            Name       = 'Name'; 
            Expression = { $_.Name.VariablePath.UserPath } 
        },
        @{ 
            Name       = 'Value'; 
            Expression = { 
                if ($_.DefaultValue.StaticType.IsArray) {
                    $_.DefaultValue.SubExpression.Statements.PipelineElements.Expression.Elements.Extent.Text
                }
                else {
                    if ($_.DefaultValue.Value) { $_.DefaultValue.Value }
                    else { $_.DefaultValue.Extent.Text }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    $result = @{ }

    $defaultValueParameters = @($ast.FindAll( {
        $args[0] -is [System.Management.Automation.Language.ParameterAst] } , 
        $true) | Where-Object { $_.DefaultValue } | 
        Select-Object @selectParams)
        
    foreach ($d in $defaultValueParameters) {
        $result[$d.Name] = foreach ($value in $d.Value) {
            # Convert '$env:' variables
            $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($value) -replace 
            "^`"|`"$|'$|^'" 
        }
    }
    $result
}
```

However, all values are of type `string`. How is it possible to get them in the correct type? The example below illustrates the issue with a hash table being returned as a string.

```
Function Test-Function {
    Param (
        [String]$ScriptName = 'Get printers',
        [HashTable]$Settings = @{ Duplex = 'Yes'}
    )
}
Get-DefaultParameterValuesHC -Path 'Test-Function'

# Output:
Name         Value
----         -----
ScriptName   'Get printers'
PaperSize    '@{ Duplex = 'Yes'}'  # String not hashTable
```

The [SafeGetValue()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45662815/how-can-i-programmatically-determine-the-default-value-of-a-function-parameter) works but only if it's not an expression. Is there a way to have it work for hash tables too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, it is possible to extract the parameters directly with:

```
$ast.Body.ParamBlock.Parameters
```

`FindAll()` is not needed in this case.

A quick-and-dirty way of achieving this would be to have the `Select-Object` parameter splat return the text representation regardless of data type, and use the [InvokeScript()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.commandinvocationintrinsics.invokescript?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0#System_Management_Automation_CommandInvocationIntrinsics_InvokeScript_System_String_System_Boolean_System_Management_Automation_Runspaces_PipelineResultTypes_System_Collections_IList_System_Object___) method to parse it when you process the results:

```
Name = 'Value';
Expression = {
    $_.DefaultValue.Extent.Text
}
```

```
$result[$d.Name] = foreach ($value in $d.Value) {
    $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.InvokeScript($value, $true)
}
```

Be aware that `InvokeScript()` will execute whatever string passed to it. Therefore, like with `Invoke-Expression`, it's important to be careful whenever it is used. For example, if `Test-Function` had this in its `param()` block:

```
[String]$ScriptName = (& cmd /c "echo This ran >%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\OhNo.txt"),
```

Running the analysis function as above would run `cmd` and write a file, even though it didn't explicitly call the target function. Therefore, it's risky to use this method with functions that run commands in the `param()` block. It would be necessary to look inside any `Pipeline` and `SubExpression` properties for each `DefaultValue` recursively, to filter out anything that shouldn't be parsed.

It is possible to recognise most types based on which properties exist for each `DefaultValue`, and customise the behaviour for each data type to recreate the original object. Similarly to how the code in the question already differentiates *arrays* from other types, exquisite type handling is the safest approach by far.

Comment: Thank you for the great help and insights. One thing of note is that `$ast.Body.ParamBlock.Parameters` only works with functions and `$ast.ParamBlock.Parameters` only works with script files. So we still have to stick to using `FindAll()` for a consistent approach. `

Comment: You're most welcome. `Get-Command` returns different types that extend `CommandInfo`, for scripts, functions etc. They all have a property `CommandType` which can be used to decide which branch to select. I tried it with a switch statement [here](https://gist.github.com/TheFreeman193/ccefde22eac1d69208390704d097f3c5).